# How to handle get request throw mp3 files in php

Tags: php, get

Consider this url: 
`http://example.com/file.mp3?hash=ajhfsjdhfjksf546sdf`

So, my question is that how can i handle this get request?

To determine whether this hash is allowed to download or not?

Comment: You could use Apache's `mod_rewrite` to create a rule that sees something like `file.mp3?hash=ajhfsjdhfjksf546sdf` and redirects it to `file.php?file=file.mp3&hash=ajhfsjdhfjksf546sdf`. Then `file.php` will be able to handle the logic of checking access.

Comment: @NickCoons Do you have a code example for this?

Comment: I posted an answer with the code for this. Please let me know if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment on your questions I suggested:

You could use Apache's `mod_rewrite` to create a rule that sees something like `file.mp3?hash=ajhfsjdhfjksf546sdf` and redirects it to `file.php?file=file.mp3&hash=ajhfsjdhfjksf546sdf`. Then `file.php` will be able to handle the logic of checking access.

Here is the code for .htaccess to accomplish this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} hash=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.mp3$ file.php?file=$1.mp3&hash=%1 [L]
```

This looks for a `hash=` value in the query string, and matches any called to `(something).mp3`.  It snags the (something) and passes it as a value to the PHP script.

Now if I call `file.mp3?hash=ajhfsjdhfjksf546sdf`, then `file.php` will have the following set:

```
$_GET['file'] == 'file.mp3'
$_GET['hash'] == 'ajhfsjdhfjksf546sdf'
```

With these values, you can now run whatever check you'd like, and if it pases, deliver `file.mp3` to the client.